# Auto Updating of Bootstrap Modal

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I am working on a requirement with the Bootstrap modal. In this I have created a table like MRVS through HTML called Name, in Modal I have created a form using sn-record-picker.

Once I select a name and click add button, it is getting added to the respective name field without any error.

After getting added, we have an edit button where the user can open the same modal of the previous entry and edit the field with another option and save. But here without even clicking the save button/update button, the edited value is getting updated to the Name column in the table.

For example: in record picker if I have options like A,B and C and if I select A and submit, it is getting submitted but if I wish to edit the value and if I open the same Modal and select B for the second time, the B is getting replaced with previous value A without even clicking the save/update button.

I want the functionality when the user edits the option second time, it should only hold the value in the field and not update/replace the previously added value A.

Only after clicking the update/save button it should replace with the new value.

How can I stop this default behavior of the modal?